# Por qué el template de recibo de messenger bot, no se muestra al usuario si pongo este timestamp "1611937882020"?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, posix

Estoy creando un bot de messenger para un restaurante, el cual debe mostrar en el template de recibo la hora exacta en que se realizó un pedido.

Lo que hice fue almacenar en una variable global el timestamp (*var tiempo*) en formato **POSIX** cada vez que se detecta un evento de mensaje. Esa variable la convierto a *string* dentro de la función que muestra el template de recibo y luego paso ese string al atributo "timestamp".

Mi problema está en que el mensaje con el template de recibo no se muestra al usuario en messenger, sin embargo en consola, veo que la API de mensajes de messenger lo envió correctamente.

Por otro lado, si en el atributo "timestamp" pongo "123123123" si se muestra al usuario la plantilla con la fecha correspondiente.
Intenté también poner por defecto este POSIX : 1611937882020 , que es de uno de los eventos recibidos y nada, tampoco se muestra.

Acá dejo un fragmento de mi código. De antemano agradezco cualquier ayuda, muchas gracias.

```
var tiempo ;

app.post('/webhook',function(req,res){
    const webhook_event = req.body.entry[0];
    if(webhook_event.messaging)
    {
        webhook_event.messaging.forEach(event =>{
            callProfileApi(event.sender.id);
            handleEvent(event.sender.id,event);
            tiempo = event.timestamp;
            console.log(event);
        });
    }
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
function handleEvent(senderId, event){
    if(event.message)
    {
        handleMessage(senderId,event.message);

        //console.log("estoy dentro de handleEvent sms");
        
    }
    else if (event.postback){
        handlePostback(senderId,event.postback.payload);
       
    }
    else if (event.quick_reply){
        handlePostback(senderId,event.quick_reply.payload);
    }
}

function receipt(senderId){
    callProfileApi(senderId);
    let nombre_usuario = username;
    let pedido_hora = String(tiempo);
    console.log("nombre en el recibo: "+ nombre_usuario );
    console.log("hora pedido: " + pedido_hora);
    console.log("direccion Particular: " + direccionParticular);
    const messageData = {
        "recipient": {
            "id": senderId
        },
        "message": {
            "attachment": {
                "type" : "template",
                "payload": {
                    "template_type": "receipt",
                    "recipient_name": nombre_usuario,
                    "order_number": "150012",
                    "currency" : "MXN",
                    "payment_method": "Efectivo",
                    "order_url":"https://google.es",
                    "timestamp": pedido_hora, // puse por defecto "1611937882020" y tampoco funciona.
                    "address":{
                        "street_1": direccionParticular,
                        "street_2": "---",
                        "city": "----",
                        "postal_code": "---",
                        "state":"CDMX",
                        "country": "Mexico"
                    },
                    "summary": {
                        "subtotal": 12.00,
                        "shipping_cost": 2.00,
                        "total_tax": 1.00,
                        "total_cost": 15.00
                    },
                    "adjustments": [
                        {
                            "name": "Descuento Frecuente",
                            "amount": 1.00
                        }     
                    ],
                    "elements": [
                        {
                            "title": "Pizza Pepperoni",
                            "subtitle":"La mejor eleccion",
                            "quantity": 1,
                            "price": 10,
                            "currency":"MXN",
                            "image_url":"https://recetaslife.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Pizza-pepperoni.jpg"
                            
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Bebida",
                            "subtitle":"Tu kola",
                            "quantity": 1,
                            "price": 2,
                            "currency":"MXN",
                            "image_url":"https://media.alamesacuba.com/media/delivery/RefrescoCiegoMontero_TuKola_alamesacuba.com_1_5.jpg"
                            
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
    callSendApi(messageData);
    console.log("mande mi recibo");
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando envias el valor `1611937882020` el cual es equivalente a `GMT: Friday, 29 January 2021 16:31:22.020` tiene precisión de milisegundos, que tal si intentas reducir la precisión de la variable `pedido_hora` a segundos dividiéndola entre 1000 a ver si funciona.